# Django admin Model name "s"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

```
class Customer(BaseModel):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="İsim")
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Soyisim")
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, unique=True,verbose_name="E-Mail")
    Adress = models.CharField(max_length=600, verbose_name="Adres")
    FaxNumber = models.CharField(max_length=600, verbose_name="Fax Numarası")

    class meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer"
```

i have a model as you can but this model name seems with "s" character in django admin panel [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUPSn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inner class name to `Meta` in title case. It should work.

Comment: thanks Also verbose_name should be verbose_name_plural